# R: How to combine several time periods

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

I have a panel data, the data frame has three individuals, each has observations for 4 periods,

```
    test.data <- data.frame(
            id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
            t = rep(1:4, 3), var1 = runif(12), var2 = runif(12)
    )
```

It should look like this

```
        id  t   var1    var2
    1   1   1   0.2851789   0.66365753
    2   1   2   0.6630548   0.07679873
    3   1   3   0.9000371   0.17182666
    4   1   4   0.8782424   0.11931904
    5   2   1   0.2642084   0.70807513
    6   2   2   0.9993678   0.48880088
    7   2   3   0.5662814   0.49188144
    8   2   4   0.7335935   0.74017649
    9   3   1   0.9868327   0.32792638
    10  3   2   0.5388366   0.05465845
    11  3   3   0.8814602   0.45199318
    12  3   4   0.9066551   0.89814063
```

Now I want to  get the average of each two consecutive time period (that is, combine t=1 and t=2 as one time period and its value be the mean of the two),and shorten the time series to 2 periods. The results should be like this

```
        id  t   var1    var2
    1   1   1   0.4495637   0.88822370
    2   1   2   0.2770255   0.68399219
    3   2   1   0.8125967   0.15395440
    4   2   2   0.6232424   0.02663445
    5   3   1   0.8965059   0.79910001
    6   3   2   0.1109559   0.47906885
```

How can I manage this?

I saw someone had already asked the same question on stackoverflow, but it's in mysql (here [How to combine several time spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885859/how-to-combine-several-time-spans)), I wonder whether there is a solution in R. (I cannot read the mysql code..)

Thanks in advance, much appreciated!

EDIT: @dimitris_ps has already given an answer for the problem, and I wonder whether there is a more generic solution. what if the data frame is like below and has 50 variables?

```
        id  t   var1    var2
    1   1   1991    0.3900957   0.49582924
    2   1   1992    0.1157777   0.50907756
    3   1   1993    0.1358916   0.05172451
    4   1   1994    0.2608382   0.25032905
    5   2   1991    0.8958081   0.97127891
    6   2   1992    0.2265558   0.73085533
    7   2   1993    0.2310969   0.63263599
    8   2   1994    0.4302372   0.48394795
    9   3   1991    0.7823354   0.75783991
    10  3   1992    0.3295121   0.78468692
    11  3   1993    0.2771166   0.59183611
    12  3   1994    0.1905194   0.64325034
```

Comment: What do you mean by "two consecutive time periods", do you want to average e.g., t1: 0.2851789 and t2: 0.6630548?

Comment: yes, that's right. sorry for the confusion, I'll try to improve the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
library(dplyr)

test.data %>% mutate(t=ceiling(t/2)) %>% group_by(id, t) %>% 
  summarise(var1=mean(var1), var2=mean(var2)) %>% ungroup
```

Also when you are creating random number use `set.seed(x)`, where `x` is some number, before, i.e.

```
set.seed(123)
test.data <- data.frame(
        id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
        t = rep(1:4, 3), var1 = runif(12), var2 = runif(12)
)
```

***Update***

A more general solution

```
test.data %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(t) %>% mutate(t=ceiling(rank(t)/2)) %>% 
  group_by(id, t) %>% summarise(var1=mean(var1), var2=mean(var2)) %>% ungroup
```

Now depending on the number of groups you want to create change the `2` in `rank(t)/2`. For example if you wanted 4 groups put `(4/# of obs per user) = 1`

Comment: Thanks @dimitris_ps, it works perfectly. I will remember to `set.seed()` next time..But I wonder if there is a more generic solution, say if `t` is not 1 to 4, but 1990 - 1993, what should I do? And also, if I have variables way more than two, say 50, then is that a generic way to deal with it? sorry I didn't think about these problems when I made the example data frame.

Comment: I suppose (as a newbie I can't tell for sure) with this updated solution I still have to deal with the variables one by one manually? apologize I can't upvote your answer because my rank is too low..

Comment: I'm thinking about something like `summarise(test.data[, i] = mean(test.data[, i])` but I know it doesn't work with the dplyr package